# How to count repeated contacts

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I am taking an *intro to programming* class and our current assignment is to create a contact manager (essentially an address book) with three classes: `name` (adds a `first`, `middle`, and `last` to a `contact`), `contact` (generates the actual `contact` itself), and `ContactManager` (keeps an array of `contacts`). I'm having trouble with one of the methods in the `ContactManger` class which is supposed to check how many of the given `contact` objects exist in the array and then returns the number of repeat `contacts`.

Here is the `ContactManager` class:

```
public class ContactManager
{
    private int nContacts;
    private Contact[] contacts;

    public ContactManager (int nMaxContact)
    {
        this.nContacts = 0;
        contacts = new Contact[nMaxContact];
    }

    /**
     * Given 4 String parameters, add a contact to the contacts array. Before adding
     * a contact to the array, do a parameter sanity check in this method.
     * If the array is full, or if first name or last name is null or an empty string, do
     * not add a contact but return false instead.
     *
     * Middle name can be left as null
     * or an empty String. Note that we allow adding duplicate contacts.
     *
     * If the name is acceptable, create a new contact and add the phone number to
     * the contact by calling the addPhoneNumber method of the Contact object. If
     * the method returns false, do not add the contact to the array and return
     * false (i.e., we discard the contact instantiated.) Otherwise, add the contact
     * to the array and return true.
     *
     * @param fName
     * @param lName
     * @param mName
     * @param phoneNumber
     *
     * @return a boolean value. See the description above
     */

    public boolean addContact (String fName, String lName, String mName, String phoneNumber)
    {
        if (fName == null || fName == "" || lName == null || lName == "" || contacts[contacts.length - 1] != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Name name;
        name = new Name(fName, lName, mName);

        Contact entry;
        entry = new Contact(name);

        Contact phone = new Contact(name);
        phone.addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

        nContacts++;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Given a Contact object, return the number of contacts with the identical name
     * (i.e., they have identical first, last, and middle name. If the input
     * parameter is null, return -1.
     *
     * For example, if the contacts array contains 10 contacts and there are 3
     * elements have the same name, return 3.
     *
     * @return an int value. See the description above.
     */

    public int countEqualContacts (Contact c)
    {
        int equal = 0;
        if (c == null)
        {
            equal = -1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
        {
            if (Contact.equals(c) == true)
            {
                equal++;
            }
        }

        return equal;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the number of contacts (int)
     */

    public int countContacts ()
    {
        return nContacts;
    }
}
```

I know that I need to call the `equals` method from the `name` and `contact` class but I don't know how to implement those since I'm still learning. Also since this is a beginner class we are not yet allowed to use `ArrayLists`. Any help on how to get the `countEqualContacts` method to work would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1553851) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0):

In Contacts class, override equals method, that return true only if all variables are equal, ex,
if(this.fname.equals(fname) && this.mName.equals(mname)..etc)
 return true;
else
 return false;

In your countEqualContyacts method, u can call this to compare and find equal objects. Careful with Null values(leaving to you how and where to check null pointer errors)